# Adjust test name in NUnit

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

We're running our test suite two times for different configurations. Our CI server aggregates them into a single report which doesn't work properly because all the test names exist twice in the NUnit report file.

Is there a way to adjust all test names, e.g., by adding a prefix, depending on a configuration value. Or in other words: is it possible to dynamically prepend a prefix to all the test names (e.g., in the SetUpFixture or something like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found it. There is an option of the console runner:

`--test-name-format="MyPrefix_{m}{a}"`

See https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line and https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Template-Based-Test-Naming for more information.

Comment: `{m}{a}` is the default test name pattern, as documented here https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Template-Based-Test-Naming